# Struggling with Css style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web

I am creating a react chat application and my 90% work has completed but i am struggling with **CSS** for better UI experience.

**I am Struggling with 2 issues:**

1. The sender and receiver are at one side only
2. If the text is too long then without going to next line it is going out of the viewing screen (Want everything inside the screen)
   When ever i was able to sift the sender part on this right hand side then only the align of the image was not same or else the img come from right side of the text to left side

### Sample Img:

[image]

## Code:

### JS Part:

```js
// few lines
<main>
    {messages && messages.map(msg => <Message key={msg.id} messageIN={msg}/>)}
    <span ref={autoScrollToDown}></span>
</main>
// few lines
function Message(props){
    
    const { text, uid, photoURL } = props.messageIN;
    const messageType = uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? 'sent' : 'received';
  
    if(messageType==='sent'){
        return(
            <div className="msgsent">
                <p>{text}</p>
                <img src={photoURL} alt="ProfilePic"/>
            </div>
        )
    } 
    else if(messageType==='received'){
        return(
            <div className="msgreceived">
                <img src={photoURL} alt="ProfilePic"/>
                <p>{text}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
    else{
        return(
            <div className="msgerror"> 
                <p>Oops! Some unexpected problem occurred</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

### CSS Part:

```css
.msgsent{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    justify-content: right;
    grid-column: 0px;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
.msgsent img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 2px 5px;
    justify-content: center;
}
.msgsent p{
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background: #6bd5ff;
    display: flex;
    color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.msgsent p:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px -10px #6bd5ff;
}
.msgreceived{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    grid-column: 0px;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
}
.msgreceived img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 2px 5px;
    justify-content: center;
}
.msgreceived p{
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background: #dddbe6;
    display: flex;
    color: black;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.msgreceived p:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px -10px #6bd5ff;
}
.msgerror{
    left: 30%;
    right: 30%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 123);
    margin: 5px 5px;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 123);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px -5px rgb(255, 255, 123);
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.msgerror:hover{
    background-color: rgba(241, 153, 153, 0.096);
    color: rgb(255, 123, 123);
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 123, 123);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px -5px rgb(255, 123, 123);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
main{
    top:95px;
    right: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 55px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-row-gap: 4px;
}
main::-webkit-scrollbar {
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 0.25rem;
} 
main::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #1e1e24;
} 
main::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #6649b8;
}
```

this are all the code please help me in making UI beauty more beautiful 
**- Thanks A Lot**

Comment: watch this one from timestamp 1.12.12(hr.m.s)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KB7JEnfc7Dc

Comment: In the class msgsent you have display listed twice. So the last display listed will override the first. You also have flex-direction listed twice. You can use Flexbox outside of your grid. You would need to create another class that wraps around all of your content. This article may help with using Flex and Grid https://blog.logrocket.com/flexbox-vs-css-grid/ Good luck!